# what's different between servlet url path and parameter?

Tags: java, url, tomcat, servlets, path

What's the difference between `localhost/user/user123`, `localhost/user?user=user123` and `localhost/?user=user123`?

How to get the parameter `user123` from a URL `localhost/user/user123` in servlet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is different between an apple and a death star? Though if each is put on a paper, the wind won't blow it away, an apple is not a death star, and vice versa. The same applies to your question too. We just don't use paths for what you want it to be used for. 

A path is considered semantically different, if it has the same parts, but in different order, this is not true for the parameters.

Comment: I am strongly suggesting [this](http://www.jpalace.org/docs/tutorials/jee/servlets_8.html) tutorial to you .You really need it .

Comment: That's a little harsh.  Try pointing him to the page that describes Path Info and Request Parameters which is all he really needs.  In the above tutorial it is page 8 of 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse from the getPathInfo() of HttpServletRequest Object.

sample code

```
String urlPath = request.getPathInfo();

System.out.println("" + urlPath.substring(urlPath.lastIndexOf("/"), urlPath.length()- 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

localhost/user/user123 looks like a RESTful way to identify a resource.

The two others aren't, I think.

Answer (score 0):

These all are accessible from **Servlet API**. Check [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), you can access all information from there.

The actual values may differ how your webapp was deployed, but usually

- `localhost` is the Context Path
- the String after that is the Servlet PAth
- the parameters after the `?` is the Query String - you have to parse it, if you want to use

Answer (score 0):

- `localhost/user/user123` - this url will be handled by pattern `/user/user123`
- `localhost/user?user=user123` - this url will be handled by pattern `/user`, with `user` parameter set to `user123` (for GET request)
- `localhost/?user=user123` - this url will be handled by pattern `/` with `user` parameter set to `user123` (again, for GET)

I don't know how to retrieve `user123` from url `localhost/user/user123` with pure servlets, but it's pretty easy with web MVC frameworks. Spring example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{user}")
    public String getUser((@PathVariable String user) {
        //here variable "user" is available and set to "user123" in your case
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you pass parameters like

```
/localhost/Servlet?parameter1=one
```

or for a JSP

```
/localhost/mypage.jsp?parameter1=one
```

In a servlet you can access the parameters by using the request object.  So generally like this:

```
String parameter1 = request.getParameter("parameter1");
```

Here is some detail on getParameter for [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

Hope this helps.